# Ajax data source (objects) :TypeError: f is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, datatables, webmethod

I am working on my ASP.Net web application where I have to populate an HTML table with Ajax data source for which I am making a use of jQuery DataTables plugin.

**HTML code:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered display" id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Prctice Group Risk No
            </th>
            <th>Practice_Group
            </th>
            <th>Risk_Category
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "type": "POST",
        "url":"index.aspx/Risky"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Prctice_Group_Risk_No" },
        { "data": "Practice_Group" },
        { "data": "Risk_Category" }]
});
```

And here is my Web Method I am making a call to to get a JSON response of list of objects

```
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod]
    public static string Risky()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(riskList);
    }
```

**JSON response from server:**

```
d:"[{"Prctice_Group_Risk_No":1,"Practice_Group":"M&A","Risk_Category":"Conflicts of Interests"},{"Prctice_Group_Risk_No":2,"Practice_Group":"abc","Risk_Category":"Client Care and Communication"}]
```

The JSON response returned seems fine to me as described in the official site of jquery DataTables 
http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

But no data is been populated in the table and I get the following error in my Firebug Console

> TypeError: f is undefined

Comment: Solved : See working Solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54146071/9222769

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, jQuery DataTables expects Ajax sourced data in the following format.

```
{ 
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

If data format differs, you need to use [`ajax.dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) to define data property for table data (`d` in your example).

I'm not ASP.NET expert but it seems that you encode your data in JSON format twice.

For your current server-side code, try this JavaScript code:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "type": "POST",
        "url":"index.aspx/Risky",
        "dataSrc": function (json) {
           return $.parseJSON(json.d);
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Prctice_Group_Risk_No" },
        { "data": "Practice_Group" },
        { "data": "Risk_Category" }
    ]
});
```

See [jQuery DataTables: Common JavaScript console errors](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-f-is-undefined) for more information on this and other common console errors.

Comment: Hello @Gyrocode.com can you please visit link to my this question and help me 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738032/jquery-datatable-passing-a-parameter-to-ajax-call-asp-net

Comment: @umer, just added an answer.