# Jquery DataTable passing a parameter to ajax call asp.net

Tags: jquery, datatables

below is my code in which I send an ajax call to my web method and get data from server to populate my HTML table, as you can see I am using Jquery DataTables to accomplish the task, and it is working fine

```
  $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "dataType": 'json',
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "type": "POST",
                "url": "index.aspx/Risky",
                "dataSrc": function (json) {
                    return $.parseJSON(json.d);
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Prctice_Group_Risk_No" },
                { "data": "Practice_Group" },
                { "data": "Risk_Category" },
            ]
        });
```

my question is how can i pass a parameter with this ajax call? I have seen everywhere on net but all those examples are about where its server side processing but here i am am using client side processing , I am not using fnsServerData or fnServerParams , Can anyone help me know how to pass a parameter with my ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ajax.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option to add or modify data submitted to the server upon an Ajax request.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   "ajax": {
       "dataType": 'json',
       "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       "type": "POST",
       "url": "index.aspx/Risky",
       "data": function (d) {
          d.extra_search = $('#extra').val();
       },
       "dataSrc": function (json) {
           return $.parseJSON(json.d);
       }
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Prctice_Group_Risk_No" },
        { "data": "Practice_Group" },
        { "data": "Risk_Category" },
     ]
});
```

Comment: Hello Gyrocode Thanx for help but its not working , its giving me the NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/RiskManager/index.aspx/Risky, It does not call the function at all , 
I have tried all the methods described in the following link
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Comment: @umer, HTTP response code 500 usually means problem with the code on the server side.

Comment: Hello @ Gyrocode.com  , that is correct i guess , it is issue with the invalid json format which server denies to accept , I have put my detailed problem into this thread  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752799/jquery-datatable-passing-a-parameter-to-ajax-call-asp-net-invalid-json-primitiv
Can you kindly help me on this ..