# Jquery DataTable passing a parameter to ajax call asp.net. Invalid JSON primitive

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, json.net

Below is my java script code to Populate my HTML table with server data and I am using Jquery DataTables to server this purpose.

```
function LoadData(result) {
$('#example').DataTable({
"ajax": {
   "dataType": 'json',
   "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   "type": "POST",
   "url": "index.aspx/Risky",
   "data": function (d) {
    return JSON.stringify( d )
    //return JSON.stringify(result);
    // d.extra_search = result;      
    //"extra_search": result

   },
   "dataSrc": function (json) {
       return $.parseJSON(json.d);
   }
},
"columns": [
    { "data": "Prctice_Group_Risk_No" },
    { "data": "Practice_Group" },
    { "data": "Risk_Category" },
 ]
});
}
```

Below is my code behind web method description

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string Risky()
{
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(riskList);
}
```

Until now its working fine, My web method gets called and my HTML table gets populated.

But my problem is that I want to pass the variable "result" as parameter to this ajax call so that my web method receives it and returns me a specific data based over this parameter.

I have visited https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data and tried to follow all of the methods described there to pass the extra data with my ajax call as you can see in my java script code three commented lines of code,I have tried this three different ways but none of it works for me causing me to a single same problem, "**Invalid JSON primitive**" with a 500 server status code in my firebug debugger. I can see in my firebug debugger that the parameter being passed to the method is "extra_search=123"

I can guess from the error description that my way of adding this extra parameter is not correct , e.g somehow it doesn't make a correct json format. but I don't know how to correct it.

Anyone kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function LoadData(result) {
   $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
                "url": "index.aspx/Risky",
                "data": function(d) {
                        d.param1  = 'param1';
                }
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "data": "Prctice_Group_Risk_No" },
            { "data": "Practice_Group" },
            { "data": "Risk_Category" }
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello Sanjay , its making same problem , 500 server status code and Invalid json primitive

Comment: 500 is the server related problem, Can you verify whether the data is reaching at the server? Can you try removing the dataSrc also?

Comment: The web method is never getting called , The error is with "Invalid json primitive" I have googled over it and there are lots of threads regarding this problem each one stating that its the problem with the json format. 
if i replace the line  "d.param1 = "ur data" with "return JSON.stringify( d )" The code works fine , There is not problem with dataSrc i guess

Comment: Can you check the edited answer. Here you specified the content type you are going to send is json, so ensure the d.param1 is of json format.

Comment: Hello Sanjax I have tried this one 
 d.param1 = JSON.parse( {"param":"Helloworld"} ) which is now throwing me an error that 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data ,

Comment: I have tried this one d.param1 =JSON.parse( '{"FileName":"Helloworld"}' ) , and it returns me the same error "Invalid json primitive" it tries send the following parameter with the call "param1%5BFileName%5D=HelloWorld"

Comment: For the time being can you check by removing the contentType in ajax request. And aslo try removing dataSrc options;

Comment: Hello Sanjay If i remove both the contentType and dataSrc , No ajax call is sent to the server (not even a wrong call i mean) , and if remove ContentType Only , That somehow works , a call is sent to Risky function and server returns me a status code 200 OK .. but then it returns me a wrong response , it returns me the whole page HTML in response , and DataTable Exception of "Invalid JSON Response occurs"
its sending now the following parameters with the call which seems ok , like a valid format param1[FileName]:"HelloWorld"

Comment: I can see from the debugger that now in the request headers the content type is 

"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" and it send the parameters
 
param1[FileName]:"HelloWorld" 
and from there if i choose the option Edit and resend in debugger and change the content type as 

"Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" , 

it response me the same error "Invalid json primitive" and this time it appends the parameter with call in the following format 

param1%5BFileName%5D=HelloWorld

Comment: Hello Sanjay I found the solution to my problem at this link https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24546/ajax-data-invalid-json-primitive-error
it was to be written as  
'data': function (d) {
     return "{FileName:"+result+"}";
       },

Answer (score 3):

With the help of @Sanjay Kumar N S and this link

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24546/ajax-data-invalid-json-primitive-error

I could be able to solve my problem. The problem was that not a valid  formatted JSON data was being sent to the server so the server was throwing an exception of "Invalid JSON Primitive"

Following is the correct format to send a an ajax call containing extra data from within the DataTable function

```
function LoadData(result) {
$('#example').DataTable({
"ajax": {
"dataType": 'json',
"contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
"type": "POST",
"url": "index.aspx/Risky",
"data": function (d) {
 return "{FileName:" + result+ "}";

},
"dataSrc": function (json) {
   return $.parseJSON(json.d);
}
},
"columns": [
{ "data": "Prctice_Group_Risk_No" },
{ "data": "Practice_Group" },
{ "data": "Risk_Category" },
]
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot! Been trying looking for the same problem for ages =)