# TypeError: f is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm creating a dataTable, where the data for the table is entirely from the database. I tried in the following way:
HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="invoice_table" class="table table-bordered table-colstriped table-hover display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Chain Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>                       
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Billable Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function year_month(year_month) {
    jQuery("#invoice_table").dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "invoice-request-db.php?mode=invoice_dataTable&year_month=" + jQuery("#year_month").val(),
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": false
    });
}
```

I'll have to pass a data, which is the year-month along with the URL, so that the datatable gets changed according to the year-month I select. But, when I try using it, I get:

> TypeError: f is undefined

which is showed in `jquery.dataTables.min.js`. What's wrong with this? What should I correct?

Comment: Does the d in dataTable need to be capitalized?

Comment: @duddosai   Which type of value in year_month?

Comment: @AnkurBhadania The value will be like 2016-05.

Comment: Could you show us the server response?

Answer (score 3):

Error in your jQuery code Replace with this. `dataTable({` is not closed

```
 jQuery("#invoice_table").DataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "invoice-request-db.php?mode=invoice_dataTable",
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": false
});
```

Comment: I've made few changes in the question, check that out.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are including `jquery.dataTables.min.js`
I had the same issue and after hours debugging I realised that I was including `dataTables.bootstrap.min.js` instead

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error here.

```
jQuery("#invoice_table").dataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "invoice-request-db.php?mode=invoice_dataTable",
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": false
    //}   <--------------------- You need to remove this. It's an extra bracket
});
```

Comment: I've made few changes in the question, check that out.

Answer (score 0):

This Javascript error generally occur if dataTable's Parameter not initialized.

Solution :

Open datatables.bootstrap.min.js in notePad and write these two line below after this line

```
var f = b.fn.dataTable;

// Code to Insert start
if(typeof f === "undefined")
return null;
// Code to insert End
```

Above

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if the table columns do not match your data elements (I removed an element, but forgot to remove the column, which was the cause of this error).