# reload datatable by ajax and json

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I'm using [datatable](https://datatables.net/) plugin and want to refresh table by ajax. I've read [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) to make my ajax return shows in table but it doesn't work. Here is my html code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="rld()">test</button>
<table id="sample_1">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th> 1 </th>
             <th> 2 </th>
             <th> 3 </th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
</table>
```

My java function:

```
function rld(){ 
    var table = $('#sample_1').DataTable( {
        ajax: '<?php echo site_url('admin/test'); ?>',
        deferRender: true,
        columns: [
            { data: '1' },
            { data: '2' },
            { data: '3' }
        ],
        rowId: 'extn',
        select: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Reload table',
                action: function () {
                    table.ajax.reload();
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
}
```

I can't get what the problem is. there in no alerts but in the console i get TypeError: f is undefined
and TypeError: c is undefined
Which i don't know why cause my json return is correct (checked in [JSONLint][3]).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33651126/244811 ?

Comment: What version of datatables are you using?

Comment: table.api().ajax.reload(null, false); 
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: @Kisaragi How can i find it?

Comment: for eg : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.10.5/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> so my datatable version is 1.10.5

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your attention :)
Found that i didn't call where the data goes when returned as json and the json field's name isn't equal to the column data field name. So make this adjustment:

```
function reload_table(){
var table = $('#sample_1').DataTable();
    table.destroy();
    var table = $('#sample_1').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "dataType": 'json',
        ajax: '<?php echo site_url('admin/relaod_table'); ?>',
        deferRender: true,
        columns: [
            { data: 'user_firstname' },
            { data: 'user_lastname' },
            { data: 'user_status' },
            { data: 'user_created_date' },
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Reload table',
                action: function () {
                    table.ajax.reload();
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
}
```